# How to queue requests in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, http, xmlhttprequest

I tried the code below to queue requests, but it does not work as expected!

```
<?php

$Sleep_Time = "10";

if (isset($_POST["String"])){

$File = "Edit_File_Content.txt";

    while(file_exists($File . "_Locked")) {
        //wait, do nothing until "Edit_File_Content.txt_Locked" file is deleted
    }

file_put_contents($File . "_Locked", "");       //create new file with same name with "_Locked" in the end (second parameter must be specified)

$File_Content = file_get_contents($File);

$File_Content .= $_POST["String"];

sleep($Sleep_Time);       //sleep for x seconds

file_put_contents($File, $File_Content);

unlink($File . "_Locked");                  //delete the above "_Locked" file

echo "String Added";
return;
}
?>

Each request takes <?php echo $Sleep_Time ?> seconds to finish!
<br><br>
<input type="button"  value="Add A" onclick='Add_String("A")'>
<input type="button"  value="Add B" onclick='Add_String("B")'>
<br><br>
<div id="Ajax_Response">Ajax Response:<br><br></div>


<script>

function Add_String(Option){      //____________________________

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', "");      //blank url (send to same page)

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     //necessary to send "String" POST key below to php

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4) {     //"4", request finished and response is ready!
        document.getElementById("Ajax_Response").innerHTML += this.responseText + "<br>";
        }
    };

http.send('String=' + Option);
}

</script>
```

The image below shows the "Ajax Response" when "Add A" and "Add B" are both clicked 5 times at once:
[image]

After all the requests are finished, "Edit_File_Content.txt" file will only contain "AA" instead of "AAAAABBBBB" string!

Any suggestions on how to effectively queue requests in php?

Comment: The connection to the server is stateless, during the first PHP script is sleeping, other threads are taking care of the incoming requests, the server doesn't wait for the first script to be executed.

Comment: @Teemu , yes I know that, that's why I used "while()" in the code example, but unfortunately it does not work as expected!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the previous answer, I used "Check_File_Write_Queue()" function, but someone alerted me that the PHP built-in function "flock()" can be used to do the same, which is correct, but I noticed something interesting, "Check_File_Write_Queue()" is more precise than "flock()", for example, if "Add A" is clicked 5 times at once, then "Add B" is clicked 5 times at once, the output in "Edit_File_Content.txt" file from "Check_File_Write_Queue()" will always be "AAAAABBBBB" and from "flock()" will vary,"AAABBABBBA","BBAABBAABA", "ABABBBAABA","BBBBBAAAAA","AAAAABBBBB",etc, which means that "Check_File_Write_Queue()" always handles the requests in the correct order and "flock()" sometimes does and sometimes does not!

Anyway, the code below is another solution that uses PHP built-in function "flock()" instead of "Check_File_Write_Queue()" function:

```
<?php

$Sleep_Time = "3";

if (isset($_POST["String"])){

    $File = "Edit_File_Content.txt";
    $File_Handle = fopen("$File", "r");
    if(flock($File_Handle, LOCK_EX)){       //on success, this script execution waits here until older scripts in queue unlock the file

    $File_Content = file_get_contents($File);

    $File_Content .= $_POST["String"];

    sleep($Sleep_Time);       //sleep for x seconds

    file_put_contents($File, $File_Content);

    flock($File_Handle, LOCK_UN);       //unlock the file so new scripts in queue can continue execution

    echo "flock() success [String Added]";
    
    }else{echo "flock() Failed";}
    fclose($File_Handle);

return;
}

?>

Each request takes <?php echo $Sleep_Time ?> seconds to finish!
<br><br>
<input type="button"  value="Add A" onclick='Add_String("A")'>
<input type="button"  value="Add B" onclick='Add_String("B")'>
<br><br>
<div id="Ajax_Response">Ajax Response:<br><br></div>

<script>

function Add_String(Option){      //____________________________

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', "");      //blank url (send to same page)

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     //necessary to send "String" POST key below to php

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     //necessary to send "String" POST key below to php

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4) {     //"4", request finished and response is ready!
        document.getElementById("Ajax_Response").innerHTML += this.responseText + "<br>";
        }
    };

http.send('String=' + Option);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the below "Check_File_Write_Queue()" function, so far, it seems to work ok!

When "Add A" and "Add B" are both clicked 5 times at once, when all the requests are finished, "Edit_File_Content.txt" file will contain "AAAAABBBBB" string as expected!

Anyway, better solutions are always welcome!

```
<?php

$Sleep_Time = "3";

if (isset($_POST["String"])){

$File = "Edit_File_Content.txt";

$File_Write_Request = Check_File_Write_Queue($File);      //add a new write request to a file and wait here until older requests are finhished

$File_Content = file_get_contents($File);

$File_Content .= $_POST["String"];

sleep($Sleep_Time);       //sleep for x seconds

file_put_contents($File, $File_Content);

Check_File_Write_Queue($File_Write_Request, "Delete");
//if the above line is not used, the "register_shutdown_function()" used in the function will ensure that the "$File_Write_Request" will be removed when script exits!

echo "String Added";
return;
}

function Check_File_Write_Queue($File, $Option = "") {        //____________________________

$Files_Write_Queue = realpath("Edit_File_Content_Check_File_Write_Queue_List.txt");

    if ($Option == "Delete" || $Option == "delete"){
    $File_Content = file_get_contents($Files_Write_Queue);
    $File_Content = str_replace($File, "", $File_Content);
    file_put_contents($Files_Write_Queue, $File_Content);
    return;
    }

$File = realpath($File);

$Request_Id = microtime() . " " . bin2hex(random_bytes(10));

$Write_Request = $File . "<<<<" . $Request_Id . ">>>>\r\n";

file_put_contents($Files_Write_Queue, $Write_Request, FILE_APPEND);

    //to prevent errors\issues, "realpath()" should be used in "register_shutdown_function()"
    register_shutdown_function(function() use ($Files_Write_Queue,$Write_Request){
    $File_Content = file_get_contents($Files_Write_Queue);
    $File_Content = str_replace($Write_Request, "", $File_Content);
    file_put_contents($Files_Write_Queue, $File_Content);
    });

    while(1) {      //1=Infinite loop
    $File_Content = file_get_contents($Files_Write_Queue);
    preg_match('/' . preg_quote($File, '/') . '<<<<(.*?)>>>>/', $File_Content, $match);
    
    if (@$match[1] == $Request_Id){return $Write_Request;}
    }
} 

?>

Each request takes <?php echo $Sleep_Time ?> seconds to finish!
<br><br>
<input type="button"  value="Add A" onclick='Add_String("A")'>
<input type="button"  value="Add B" onclick='Add_String("B")'>
<br><br>
<div id="Ajax_Response">Ajax Response:<br><br></div>


<script>

function Add_String(Option){      //____________________________

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open('POST', "");      //blank url (send to same page)

http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');     //necessary to send "String" POST key below to php

    http.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState === 4) {     //"4", request finished and response is ready!
        document.getElementById("Ajax_Response").innerHTML += this.responseText + "<br>";
        }
    };

http.send('String=' + Option);
}

</script>
```